# Error when running rake db:migrate

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, vps

I'm following the railscast where Ryan sets up a VPS. But I need to install mysql instead of postgresql.

when I run the cap deploy:cold command, it all seems to run fine, until it runs the bundle, which fails when trying to install the mysql2 gem.

so i logged into the server and installed it manually (the database had already been setup).

but when i run the rake db:migrate command I keep getting this error:

```
rake aborted!
database configuration does not specify adapter

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => db:load_config
```

in the database.yml file i have the following

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: blog_production
  pool: 5
  username: blog
  password: *****
  host: localhost
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

I've edited the socket from default, added and removed the host line, and installed the gem manually, but nothing seems to make it work!

Answer (score 5):

This usually happens when your deployment scripts or the currently logged in user on the VPS have not set the RAILS_ENV environment variable. Then it defaults to 'development' and your database.yml would have no configuration for that environment. So try

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:migrate --trace
```

instead.

Comment: Thank I've tried this now, but I'm getting this error... rake aborted!
undefined method `accept' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Can you run it with the trace argument and post the result? I updated the answer.

Comment: I've solved the problem by replacing the database.yml file, maybe there was some problem with the indentation on this file, but now it ran the migrations without problems... cool!

Answer (score 2):

Corrupt yml file solved it for me.

Renamed and recreated the database.yml file and it worked.